# better approach for using viewpager with fragments having listviews being populated from webservice call?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, asynctaskloader

First I explain the structure of my app. To be precise *MainActivity* of my app contains *Viewpager* with two *fragments*. Each *fragment* contains a *listview*. The data inside listview is being populated from web service call.

This web service call is actually done *in activity not in the fragments* through *AsyncTaskLoader* which loads data for both listviews and saves the response in two *Application* variables (Lists of data for both listviews). On finish of loader , i just do *viewpager.notifydatasetchanged()* (which reloads the fragments , thus sets the data in listview).

As the fragments in viewpager are initialiased by viewpager's adapter no by the activity directly, I found this approach better.

Options I had, but rejected (pls correct me If I could utilise them)

- Asynctask to call webservice (headache if handling rotations)
- IntentService (updation of UI)

Is there any other approach to load data and handles the fragments?

Comment: Contentproviders + Loaders api

Comment: i  faced same problem... anyone have solution of this problem....... @Avisharma

Comment: @Selvin.. plz share any example code of this problem